# VisualClusters extension in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, viewer

I have VisualClusters extension in my Forge viewer v7 and it worked well with revit files, but now it stoped working even if I didn't touch that code... It throws error for AnimState.js: "i.createObjctAnimStates is not a function".
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to tell what happened without investigating. Could you share a non-confidential, minimum, runnable code example and a non-confidential model to `forge (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`?

Comment: Hi Eason, after long day of debugging I found out that metro4.js library that I use for creating 3 resizable panels in my app somehow blocks loading of visual cluster extension... Thank you for answering!

Comment: NP, thank you very much for your good news.